# Prompt on vim startup

Tags: vim

Whenever I open a file in vim (using `vim filename`) I get presented first with the following prompt:

```
"filename" 44L, 1055C
--- Local option values ---
  autoindent          cursorline          grepprg=            makeprg=            path=               smartindent         textwidth=79
--autoread            define=             include=            nrformats=hex       relativenumber      syntax=javascript   undofile
  colorcolumn=80      errorformat=        keywordprg=         number              scroll=21           tabstop=2
  cryptmethod=        expandtab           list                numberwidth=5       shiftwidth=2        tags=
  fileencoding=utf-8
  filetype=javascript
  formatoptions=qrn1
  iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,$
--- Local option values ---
  autoindent          cursorline          grepprg=            makeprg=            path=               smartindent         textwidth=79
--autoread            define=             include=            nrformats=hex       relativenumber      syntax=javascript   undofile
  colorcolumn=80      errorformat=        keywordprg=         number              scroll=21           tabstop=2
  cryptmethod=        expandtab           list                numberwidth=5       shiftwidth=2        tags=
  fileencoding=utf-8
  filetype=javascript
  formatoptions=qrn1
  iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,$
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How can I disable this prompt? It doesn't happen when I open the editor without filenames as arguments.

Comment: You have to post your `.vimrc`.

Comment: It looks like something is calling `:setlocal` a couple of times, perhaps instead of actually setting a local option to a value.

Comment: Search for an autocommand that does `:setlocal` on your vimrc.

Answer (score 0):

Sergi, you can reproduce the same by executing `:setlocal` (or `setl`) command. I.e. in your case this command was executed without an option.
Here is the fragment from the help which explains that:

```
:setl[ocal] ... Like ":set" but set only the value local to the
                current buffer or window.  Not all options have a
                local value.  If the option does not have a local
                value the global value is set.
                With the "all" argument: display local values for all
                local options.
                Without argument: Display local values for all local
                options which are different from the default.
                When displaying a specific local option, show the
                local value.  For a global/local boolean option, when
                the global value is being used, "--" is displayed
                before the option name.
                For a global option the global value is
                shown (but that might change in the future).
```

So you need to check your .vimrc, autocommands and user defined functions to find where the issue actually appears. Did you remember what you've changed in your .vimrc (or other vim files) before the issue is happened for the first time?